# how could i import database from openLCA to brightway2

Tags: brightway

The software I used before was openLCA, I applied for ecoinvent database, now I want to try using brightway2, I want to know how to import openLCA database into brightway2

now I want to try using brightway2, I want to know how to import openLCA database into brightway2